# os.OpenFile threw "permission denied" on a file that has mode 0666

Tags: linux, go

This is the code:

```golang
func main() {
    _, err := os.OpenFile("/tmp/kd.log", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0o666)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I use `root` user to run it to open a file created by another user:

```
root in ~ λ la /tmp/kd.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 k k 3.0M Dec 12 16:57 /tmp/kd.log
```

And it threw:

```
panic: open /tmp/kd.log: permission denied

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /tmp/t/t.go:13 +0x45
exit status 2
```

I tried `lsof /tmp/kd.log` but got no output. So this file isn't used by other process.

Now that it has `-rw-rw-rw-` permission, this kind of error shouldn't occur.

I don't know if I overlooked some basic details. Apologize if I asked a silly question.

Comment: On Unix-like systems, permission to _create_ a file is controlled by the `w` bits on the directory to contain the file. I think the error would go away, should you drop `os.O_CREATE` from the flags, but anyway it's tangential to the reason for the error.

Comment: Yes, removing O_CREATE did get rid of the answer. But like you said, it shouldn't cause the error. According the doc this flag only take effect if the file doesn't exist. And "create if not exists" is what I need in my app. @kostix

Comment: I would say the doc may just be moot on this topic: implementing (in the kernel) what you are after wold be complicated: the kernel must take some sort of a lock on the directory, then check whether the file exists or not and then check the perms on the directory or the file itself based on the outcome. A simpler and race-free approach is to just notice `O_CREAT` and immediately try to actually create-and-open the file, reverting to plain opening if that fails with `EEXIST`. But indeed this is a very interesting question. POSIX seems to not define this precisely.

Comment: It's interesting that googling for this yields only [this](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-kernel/20110506001210.540946245@clark.kroah.org/) and [this](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/10742)… Do you have some kind of _weird_ setup? ;-)

Comment: Hi, I noticed `sticky bit` from the second post. I think maybe this problem is related to `/tmp` path because it has sticky bit. @kostix

Comment: «maybe this problem is related to /tmp path because it has sticky bit»–quite possibly indeed: it should have `S_ISVTX` set on Linux-based systems (at least). I'd research whether you happen to hit the conditions for [`fs.protected_regular`](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html#protected-regular).